# Better graph visualization in GraphStream - JAVA

Tags: java, swing, graph, graphstream

I am working on [GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org/) Library for java. But I am facing a problem here.
I tried to query 10,000 records having 2 columns from database. And the graph create 2 nodes and one edge for each row. 
But when I try to run the program, the graph looks very complicated. See the below image.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class GraphExplore {
    static Connection conn2;
    static String result, result2;
    static int totalRows, i;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    showData();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void showData() throws SQLException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GRAPH");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout()) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 5));

        Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Tutorial", false, true);

        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:G:/hs_data/h2_db/test", "sa", "sa");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Statement stmt2 = conn2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM cdr");
        while (rs.next()) {
            totalRows = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT ANUMBER,BNUMBER FROM CDR LIMIT 1000");
        while (rs2.next()) {
            result = rs2.getString("ANUMBER");
            result2 = rs2.getString("BNUMBER");
            graph.addNode(result);
            graph.addNode(result2);
            for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                graph.addEdge("string" + i, result, result2);
        }

        graph.setAutoCreate(true);
        graph.setStrict(false);
        Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_GUI_THREAD);
        ViewPanel viewPanel = viewer.addDefaultView(false);
        viewer.enableAutoLayout();
        panel.add(viewPanel);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (Node node : graph) {
            node.addAttribute("ui.label", node.getId());
        }

        // graph.addAttribute("ui.stylesheet", "graph { fill-color: red; }");text-mode:
        // hidden;
        graph.addAttribute("ui.stylesheet", "node {size:12px;fill-color:#ff0000;}");
        graph.addAttribute("ui.stylesheet", "edge { shape:angle ;fill-color:#222;}");

    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me, how to give better visualization to this graph. OR I have to use some other graphs available. I am using the very basic [example](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Storing-retrieving-and-displaying-data-in-graphs/) of GraphStream.

Comment: Any luck with [*Zooming and panning*](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation/#zooming-and-panning)?

Comment: yes, i have tried these but I got error on this line `viewPanel.setViewCenter(440000, 2503000, 0);` It is asking me to add cast to `viewPanel`

Comment: Can you get a reference via `View view = viewer.getDefaultView()`?

Comment: I am using `ViewPanel viewPanel = viewer.addDefaultView(false);` For now, i Have successfully enabled the zoom by this line of code `viewPanel.getCamera().setViewPercent(0.25);` But how can I see the other part of graph by moving left or right ?

Comment: Once you select any node, you can use the arrow keys to pan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`ViewPanel`](https://data.graphstream-project.org/api/gs-core/current/org/graphstream/ui/swingViewer/ViewPanel.html), get a reference to the [`Camera`](https://data.graphstream-project.org/api/gs-core/current/org/graphstream/ui/view/Camera.html) and use it to set the zoom percentage and center.

```
viewPanel.getCamera().setViewPercent(0.25);
viewPanel.getCamera().setViewCenter(0, 0, 0);
```

Once any node is selected or the `viewPanel` gains [focus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html),

```
viewPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
```

- Use the <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> keys to pan.
- Use the <kbd>page up</kbd> and <kbd>page down</kbd> keys to zoom.